# BWA fail to locate the index files

Tags: bioinformatics, sequence-alignment

I'm currently working on trying to analyze a dataset. I'm new to the field of bioinformatics and was trying to use BWA tools, however, as soon as I reach bwa mem, I keep running into the same error:

input --> `mirues-macbook:sra ipmiruek$ bwa mem -t 8 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.17.fa ERR3841737/ERR3841737_trimmed.fq.gz > ERR3841737/ERR3841737_mapped.sam`

output --> `[E::bwa_idx_load_from_disk] fail to locate the index files`

I've already indexed the reference chromosome as such:

`bwa index Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.17.fa.gz`

Is there anything I could do to fix this problem? Thank you.

I tried changing the dataset that I was using along with the corresponding reference chromosome but it still yielded the same result. Is this an issue with the code or with the dataset I'm working with?

Comment: What is the output of `bwa index Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.17.fa.gz`? Did you run this command in the same directory as the mapping command? Can BWA index from a gzipped file or maybe you need to unzip first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you indexed a gzip-compressed FASTA file, but are supplying an index base (idxbase) without the `.gz` extenstion. What you want is:

```
$ bwa mem \
    -t 8 \
    Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.17.fa.gz \ 
    ERR3841737/ERR3841737_trimmed.fq.gz \
    > ERR3841737/ERR3841737_mapped.sam
```

Alternatively, `gunzip` the reference FASTA file and index it. For example:

```
$ gunzip Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.17.fa.gz
$ bwa index Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.17.fa
```

Note that BWA packs the reference sequences (into the `.pac` file), so you don't even need the FASTA file to run BWA MEM after it's been indexed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just tried out the code above and it worked! I wasn't really sure where I had gone wrong and this kept occurring several times, but your explanation was incredibly helpful. Thanks, again.